# Facebook permissions for viewing photos

Tags: python, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a Facebook application that accesses the user's friends' photos.  For some reason, I can only access certain photos.

I have narrowed it down to only being able to access photos with the 'Friends of Friends' privacy setting turned ON.

The pictures I can't access still have the 'Friends' privacy settings turned ON, but the user the Application is acting on behalf of is friends with these people, so as per Facebook's privacy scheme, I should be able to access them.

I can access the photos via the Facebook site.

My application has the following permissions: `user_photos`, `friends_photos`.

I'm not receiving any OAuth errors, I'm merely getting nothing back from the server (e.g. if the user has all their photos set to 'Friends only' I get a blank data{} array from a `/UserID/albums` API call.

Anyone know what's happening?  Should I be requesting more permissions from my App users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a privacy setting which can override this, check the settings on the friends' account to see what their options for 'How people bring your info to apps they use' setting is - it's on https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy and allows users to stop apps their friends use from accessing any data about them, even if it would normally be available to that friend.

Comment: Thanks Igy. This works for app users, but is there a way to check the 'How people bring your info to apps they use' settings on a user's friends?

Comment: Nope, there's no way to check this setting